# Use Azure Iothub_client examples in own code

Tags: c, azure, cmake, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to use the AMQPoverWebsockets-Client example from the C-SDK of Azure-iothub.

How do I link the specific libraries to the makefile to compile it successfully?

I tried to write the path down in my makefile. But it didn't work.
Here is my makefile so far:

```
SENSOR=mcp9808
SENSOR2=adxl345x    
SENSOR3=init
SENSOR4=filestorage

IOT1=src/iothubtransporthttp.c.o
IOT2=src/iothub_client_ll.c.o
IOT3=src/iothub_message.c.o
IOT4=src/platform_linux.c.o
IOT5=src/crt_abstractions.c.o

all:
    gcc -Wall -c $(SENSOR).c -o $(SENSOR).o -lm -lwiringPi -lrt
    gcc -Wall -c $(SENSOR2).c -o $(SENSOR2).o -lm -lwiringPi -lrt
    gcc -Wall -c $(SENSOR4).c -o $(SENSOR4).o -lm -lwiringPi -lrt   
    gcc -Wall -c $(SENSOR3).c -o $(SENSOR3).o -lm -lrt `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
    #gcc -Wall $(IOT1) $(IOT2) $(IOT3) $(IOT4) $(IOT5) iothub_client_sample_http.c -o iot_client -lm -lrt
    gcc -Wall $(SENSOR).o $(SENSOR2).o $(SENSOR3).o $(SENSOR4).o main.c -o main -lm -lwiringPi -lrt `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`       

clean:
    rm *.o > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: What's the error or warning messages?

Comment: In the file azure/iothub_client_ll is agenttime.h included:

#include "azure_c_shared_utility/agenttime.h" 
And the file is in the respective folder.
Make shows this error:
azure/iothub_client_ll.h:26:46: fatal error: azure_c_shared_utility/agenttime.h: No such file or directory

Comment: It's not a linking problem, the compiler could not find the header file. Try add the directory contains `azure_c_shared_utility` to gcc flags, like `-I <dir>`.

Comment: Now there is an other error message, but the mentioned file exists `gcc -Wall -c iothub_client_sample_http.c -o iothub_client_sample_http.o -lm -lrt -I azure/azure_c_shared_utility -I azure-c-shared-utility -I azure_c_shared_utility
In file included from azure/iothub_client_ll.h:26:0,
                 from iothub_client_sample_http.c:15:
azure/azure_c_shared_utility/agenttime.h:16:49: fatal error: azure_c_shared_utility/umock_c_prod.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`